# getting error : nodeman app crashed -waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: mongoose, meanjs

After using grunt command
I am getting this error I have updated the bower and re install npm? not understating first it was running fine but now after using grunt it is showing error as-

Answer (score 2):

Try to **remove** `node_modules` folder and **run** `npm install`.